# How can i create xpath below this code

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to create xpath this (Unscheduled Visitor Check-In) button. i am unable to find the button name or id. can anyone help me out from this issue please. will appreciate that. please see the attachment.

```
<div id="SAFEControl307369" class="buttontextactivestyle" uniquefieldid="307369" onselectstart="return false" onchange="setAttribute('IsModified','1');" onclick=" document.body.style.cursor = 'wait'; window.location.href = 'QSForm.aspx?FormID=194&Hidden=1';return false;" datatype="" boundcolumn="" ismodified="0" style="position:absolute;left:280px;top:5px;height:0px;width:250px; ;" caption="" tabindex="-1">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:20px;cursor:pointer;">
<td class="buttonleftactivestyle"/>
<td class="buttonmiddleactivestyle" align="center">
<div>Unscheduled Visitor Check-In</div>
[Screenshot of the application with xpath][1]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below xpath:

```
//div[contains(.,'Unscheduled Visitor Check-In')]
```

You can try the code below:

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your XPath"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Feel free to change the locator in the code above. Try to with xpath provided by the firepath as shown in image.

Comment: welcome Satyajit .. can you please accept the answer if it really works for you

Comment: sorry bro,by typing mistaken i was replied "it's now working"  my reply will be "it not working" ,i am extremely sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='SAFEControl307369']/table/tbody/div"));
```

When you checking the element you need look on the try for create the XPath.

Comment: thanks for your help,but sorry this code not working